# getting CSI/tbsd_ & CSI/_tbnd data in facebook login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm using Facebook Login to get data from users that make a login to my website and i'm using the console.log function.

The only things that the console displays me are the following:

CSI/tbsd_ & CSI/_tbnd

What does it mean? What could be the problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The log entries for `CSI/tbsd_` and `CSI/_tbnd` are actually time stamps, which are generated by some APIs.

Time stamps can be generated in JavaScript using the [`console.timeStamp()` function](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.timeStamp).

You can also see these time stamp logs on google.com:

[image]

Therefore I assume the time stamps you see actually come from some Google APIs.

Within Firebug they are even displayed as olive lines within the [*Net* panel timeline](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Timeline):

[image]

So these log messages are nothing to worry about. They just provide some information for debugging purposes.